# Pregunta sobre Python + Kivy para desarrolar una APP para Android

Tags: python, app, kivy

Estoy comenzando a trabajar en mi primera app móvil con Python. Pienso utilizar el framework Kivy. el proyecto es hacer una aplicación de marcador o pizarra de baloncesto. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](Algo como lo que se muestra en la imagen anexa). Ya tengo parte del código hecho solo en caracteres por pantalla (sin usar kivy). Para concretar, mi pregunta seria como lograr con Python + Kivy utilizar ese tipo de fuente tipo Led de 7 segmentos en los números para que la aplicación tenga un aspecto parecido a una pantalla real? Gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: No se de kivy, pero sospecho que tendrás que conseguir una "fuente de led" en internet, diseñar vos la fuente, o escribir un programa que se encargue de dibujar las letras.

Answer (score 1):

La opción "facil" es usar una fuente con esa estética como te comenta Dante S., puedes empezar buscando en la web "segment display fonts" y encontraras múltiples opciones. En ultima instancia también puedes crear tu tu propia fuente, aunque eso ya no es tan fácil.

Puedes agregar/registrar fuentes personalizadas a kivy con [kivy.core.text.LabelBase](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.text.html#kivy.core.text.LabelBase), algo como:

```
LabelBase.register(name='MiFuente', fn_regular='MiFuente-VariableFont_wght.ttf')
```

tras lo que podrás usar la fuente mediante la propiedad `font_name` de los widgets (Label, Button, etc).

Otra opción no tan convencional pero mas divertida es emular con Kivy un segment display. Kivy expone múltiples funciones de bajo nivel de OpenGl a traves de `kivy.graphics` que permiten dibujar programaticamente. Un ejemplo emulando un visualizador de siete segmentos clásico muy simple:

```
import itertools

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Mesh

KV = """
<SevenSegmentsDisplay@Widget>:
    seg_spacing: 3
    seg_width: 10
    seg_height: 60
    segments_on: ""
    background_color: (0, 0, 1, 1)
    foreground_color: (0, 0, 0.2, 0.6)

    canvas:
        #############
        # A segment #
        #############
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color if "A" in self.segments_on else self.foreground_color
        Mesh:
            mode: "triangle_fan"
            vertices: [\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing, root.y + self.seg_height * 2 + self.seg_spacing * 4 + 1, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing + self.seg_height, root.y + self.seg_height * 2 + self.seg_spacing * 4 + 1, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing + self.seg_height - self.seg_width, root.y + self.seg_height * 2 + self.seg_spacing * 4 + 1 - self.seg_width, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_width + self.seg_spacing, root.y + self.seg_height * 2 + self.seg_spacing * 4 + 1 - self.seg_width, 0, 0\
                ]
            indices: [0, 1, 2, 3]
        
        #############
        # B segment #
        #############
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color if "B" in self.segments_on else self.foreground_color

        Mesh:
            mode: "triangle_fan"
            vertices: [\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing * 2 + self.seg_height, root.y + self.seg_height * 2 + self.seg_spacing * 3 + 1, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing * 2 + self.seg_height, root.y + self.seg_height + self.seg_spacing * 3 + 1, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing * 2 + self.seg_height - self.seg_width, root.y + self.seg_height + self.seg_spacing * 3 + 1 + self.seg_width / 2, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing * 2 + self.seg_height - self.seg_width, root.y + self.seg_height * 2 + self.seg_spacing * 3 + 1 - self.seg_width, 0, 0\
                ]
            indices: [0, 1, 2, 3]
        
        #############
        # C segment #
        #############
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color if "C" in self.segments_on else self.foreground_color
 
        Mesh:
            mode: "triangle_fan"
            vertices: [\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing * 2 + self.seg_height, root.y + self.seg_height + self.seg_spacing, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing * 2 + self.seg_height, root.y + self.seg_spacing, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing * 2 + self.seg_height - self.seg_width, root.y + self.seg_spacing + self.seg_width, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing * 2 + self.seg_height - self.seg_width, root.y + self.seg_height + self.seg_spacing - self.seg_width / 2, 0, 0\
                ]
            indices: [0, 1, 2, 3]
            
        #############
        # D segment #
        #############
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color if "D" in self.segments_on else self.foreground_color

        Mesh:
            mode: "triangle_fan"
            vertices: [\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing + self.seg_height, root.y, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing, root.y, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing + self.seg_width, root.y + self.seg_width, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing + self.seg_height - self.seg_width, root.y + self.seg_width, 0, 0\
                ]
            indices: [0, 1, 2, 3]
            
        #############
        # E segment #
        #############
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color if "E" in self.segments_on else self.foreground_color

        Mesh:
            mode: "triangle_fan"
            vertices: [\
                root.x, root.y + self.seg_spacing, 0, 0,\
                root.x, root.y + self.seg_spacing + self.seg_height, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_width, root.y + self.seg_spacing + self.seg_height - self.seg_width / 2, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_width, root.y + self.seg_spacing + self.seg_width, 0, 0\
                ]
            indices: [0, 1, 2, 3]
            
        #############
        # F segment #
        #############
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color if "F" in self.segments_on else self.foreground_color

        Mesh:
            mode: "triangle_fan"
            vertices: [\
                root.x, root.y + self.seg_spacing * 3 + 1 + self.seg_height, 0, 0,\
                root.x, root.y + self.seg_spacing * 3 + 1 + self.seg_height * 2, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_width, root.y + self.seg_spacing * 3 + 1 + self.seg_height * 2 - self.seg_width, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_width, root.y + self.seg_spacing * 3 + 1 + self.seg_height + self.seg_width / 2, 0, 0\
                ]
            indices: [0, 1, 2, 3]
            
        #############
        # G segment #
        #############
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color if "G" in self.segments_on else self.foreground_color

        Mesh:
            mode: "triangle_fan"
            vertices: [\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing, root.y + self.seg_spacing * 2 + 1 + self.seg_height, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing + self.seg_width, root.y + self.seg_spacing * 2 + 1 + self.seg_height + self.seg_width / 2, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing - self.seg_width + self.seg_height, root.y + self.seg_spacing * 2 + 1 + self.seg_height + self.seg_width / 2, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing + self.seg_height, root.y + self.seg_spacing * 2 + 1 + self.seg_height, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing + self.seg_height - self.seg_width, root.y + self.seg_spacing * 2 + self.seg_height - self.seg_width / 2, 0, 0,\
                root.x + self.seg_spacing + self.seg_width, root.y + self.seg_spacing * 2 + self.seg_height - self.seg_width / 2, 0, 0\
                ]
            indices: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

<DisplayTest@RelativeLayout>:
    SevenSegmentsDisplay:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: (250, 501)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        id: display
        seg_spacing: 5
        seg_width: 40
        seg_height: 240
        
DisplayTest:


"""      
        
        
class DisplayTest(RelativeLayout):
    NUMS = {
        "0": "ABCDEF",
        "1": "BC",
        "2": "ABDEGD",
        "3": "ABCDG",
        "4": "BCFG",
        "5": "ACDFG",
        "6": "ACDEFG",
        "7": "ABC",
        "8": "ABCDEFG",
        "9": "ABCFG"}
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.num_iter = itertools.cycle(self.NUMS.values())
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)
        
    def update(self, *args):
        self.ids.display.segments_on = next(self.num_iter)

        
class SevenSegmentsDisplayApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SevenSegmentsDisplayApp().run()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]